# Laying out html 5 page with CSS

Tags: css, html

I'm rebuilding a personal site to learn some more about HTML 5. In the process, I'm moving my blog posts to use some of the new HTML 5 elements such as header/article/section/aside. To give an example, by blog posts have the following format:

## My Blog Post Title

[Blog publish date goes here]

A single paragraph that provides an overview of the content.

### [My First Subtitle]

The content associated with the first subtitle

### [My second subtitle]

The content associated with the second subtitle

[Comments Go Here]

In addition to this, I will have some content, perhaps a quote or a graphic out to the right of the post. I have two challenges: 1) I'm not sure how to use the HTML 5 elements in relation to each other, in particular article and section are confusing me. 2) How to get my aside element to be to the right of the rest of my content. Currently, I have the following:

```
<header>
  <h1>My Blog Post Title</h1>
  <p>Published <time datetime='18-06-2013'>June 6, 2013</time></p>
</header>

<div>
  <article>
    <p>A single paragraph that provides an overview of the content.</p>
    <section>
      <header>My first subtitle</header>
      The content associated witht he first subtitle.
    </section>

    <section>
      <header>My second subtitle</header>
      The content associated with the second subtitle.
    </section>
  </article>

  <aside>
    My right side content. This area should take up 33% of the entire width.
  </aside>
</div>
```

Am I on the right path? I see all sorts of stuff about article vs section? Either way, currently, my `aside` content appears below my article content. In reality, I want it beside it. Does anyone know the appropriate way with CSS to provide this kind of layout?

Thank you

Comment: Header is a grouping element:  it groups all of the heading content together, not for marking up a headline.  You should be using h1 instead.  If your heading element only contains a headline, then you don't need it at all, just the h1 will do.

Comment: I'm not a HTML5 guru myself, but I've got the feeling that an article is "smaller" than a section. I think the official documentation says somewhere that on a forum, a section can be the replies part of the page, while each of the individual replies are articles.

Comment: @MrLister No, article is an element that's able to stand on its own.  If you were to copy and paste it into another website or find it in an RSS feed, would it still make sense?  If yes, then it is an article, otherwise it could be a section, aside, etc.

Comment: I would wrap the whole post with an `article` element. Including `header`

Comment: Here is a tutorial teaching you how to style elements on the page using CSS: http://learnlayout.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess there is no "perfect" answer to this yet. But I give it a try.

```
<article class="post">
    <div class="left-side">
        <header>
            <h1>My Blog Post Title</h1>
            <p>Published <time datetime='18-06-2013'>June 6, 2013</time></p>
        </header>

        <section>
            A single paragraph that provides an overview of the content.
        </section>

        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>My first subtitle</h1>
            </header>
            <p>The content associated witht he first subtitle.</p>
        </section>

        <section>
            <header>
                <h1>My second subtitle</h1>
            </header>
            <p>The content associated with the second subtitle.</p>
        </section>
    </div>

    <div class="right-side">
        <aside>
            My right side content. This area should take up 33% of the entire width.
        </aside>
    </div>
</article>
```

I would wrap the whole blog post in an article and divide its parts into section.

The part with the floating `aside` :

```
.right-side, .left-side {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.right-side {
    width: 33%;        
    float: right;
}

.left-side {
    width: 67%;
    float: left;
}
```

And a clearfix for the `floats`:

```
.post:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: The aside content still appears below the main content though. Am I missing something?

Comment: Isn't the `aside` content part of your blog post?

Comment: It's not quite clear if the `aside` is related to your posts or to the whole page in your question.

Comment: The aside content should be part of the post. From what I can tell in the HTML you wrote, it looks like aside is related to the post since it is in the same article. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I thought the `aside` content is something related to the post. Then, in my opinion, it is correct to place it inside the `<article>`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) this is modern way to layout the page components. In http://html5doctor.com/ you should search for header/ aside / footer / section and other elements to understand more about them. [And here](http://html5doctor.com/avoiding-common-html5-mistakes/) is a good article about avoiding most common html5 structuring mistakes.

Comment: I'd be very cautious about flexbox, [support is poor](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Answer (score 0):

1)Html5 introuduced `<Section>` and `<article>` tags purely for Semantics. It means what would you use to give a  meaningful description to your code. When you see it in the Browser they both will appear the same.

```
For e.g. Articles make more sense when you show forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.
```

Use Section when you are showing some information to the user e.g FAQs, Product Info.

And if your data cannot semantically defined simply use a `<div>`

Here is a good example explaining the difference

```
http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/
```

I also noticed you are using `<header>` and nesting `<h1>`. This is not needed. Either use `<header>` or `<h1>` since they both have the same meaning. This will make more sense when you create a page as per ‎Web accessibility standards.